# Django "ImportError at /"

Tags: python, django

I am getting an import error on a very basic test site I am trying.  Below is the error message:

```
ImportError at /

No module named tickets

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://dcdev1.dcevolve.com/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named tickets

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py     in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/django/dcdev1',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 5 Aug 2013 02:58:39 -0500
```

My directory structure is this:

```
-/home/django/dcdev1
-/home/django/manage.py
-/home/django/tickets
```

Under dcdev1 there are `__init__.py`  `__init__.pyc`  `settings.py`  `settings.pyc`  `urls.py`  `urls.pyc`  `wsgi.py`  `wsgi.pyc`

Under tickets there are

`__init__.py`  `__init__.pyc`  `models.py`  `models.pyc`  `templates`  `tests.py`  `views.py`  `views.pyc`

Relevant settings.py sections:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "tickets/templates",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tickets',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from tickets.models import ticket_info
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'dcdev1.tickets.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^dcdev1/', include('dcdev1.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class ticket_info(models.Model):
    from_address = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    to_address = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    subject_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    recv_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from tickets.models import ticket_info

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

I am working off of the guide at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/

There seems to be some differences in his directory structure vs mine. I'm guessing something had changed in later django versions.  I have never used django, just trying it out to see if it will work for a project.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the root directory set to? My guess is, you might have to specify `django.tickets` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: I get an "import error no module named tickets" when trying to start the server after changing to django.tickets.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` comment clearly tells you not to use relative paths, you are using a relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In urls.py
try these

```
url(r'^$', 'tickets.views.home', name='home'),
```

instead of these

```
url(r'^$', 'dcdev1.tickets.views.home', name='home'),
```

Also you can run `python manage.py validate` and maybe you will see something useful.